# getting NoMethodError: undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass in rspec

Tags: rspec, capybara, rspec-rails

```
def self.verify_the_order_of_channels(firstwebapp,secondwebapp,firstmobileapp,secondmobileapp)
  expect(firstmobileapp).to be > firstwebapp
  expect(firstmobileapp).to be >  secondwebapp
end
```

Comment: gems used : rspec-expectation 3.5, rspec-support 3.5. rspec 3.5

Comment: This doesn't provide nearly enough info about your code or what your problem is.  What is `firstwebapp`, `secondwebapp`, etc.  From the error it's obvious that one of them is being passed in as nil, but are they even types where comparing with `>` makes sense?

Comment: these are variables. My problem is I'm not able use matcher or expectation in rspec script if I use > i.e greater than symbol.

Answer (score 1):

`firstmobileapp` is being passed in as `nil`, and `>` is not defined for `nil`.  You need to look at whatever is calling `verify_the_order_of_channels` and see why it's passing `nil` through, or rewrite the expectation to check for nil first (which will then error when it is nil and you'll still have to figure out why it's being passed in as nil)

```
def self.verify_the_order_of_channels(firstwebapp,secondwebapp,firstmobileapp,secondmobileapp)
  expect(firstmobileapp).not_to be_nil
  expect(firstmobileapp).to be > firstwebapp
  ...
end
```